# React.js passing a handleClick method down from App to List to ListItem?

Tags: reactjs

Quick question about good form in a React.js app:

I have a top-level App that has a state like "selectedItem", and want a ListItem component to be able to change that state.

So you make a top-level method on App like `selectItem: function(item)` that does a `setState(selectedItem: item)`.

App passes this function down as a property to List component.

List component passes this function down as a property to ListItem component.

Finally ListItem component uses it as the onClick handler, with a `.bind(null, item)` so that the top-level state can be changed by a clicked item in the list.

Is this right?

It seems quite messy.  Seems it'd be nicer for the ListItem to be able to call App.selectItem(item) directly without it having to be passed down three times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ListItem` is directly aware of `App` and its `selectItem` method, then `ListItem` is coupled to that application—it can never be reused in any other context. For components to be reusable, they should generally take a change (or whatever) handler as a property that it will call when appropriate.

As for components that *are* specific to your application (that is, they're not meant to be reusable), all that passing around can get messy. There's an architecture called [flux](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html) that allows application-specific views (known as "controller-views") to interact with an application-wide dispatcher in much the way that you mention.

In short, reusable components should be passed props to make them maximally portable; application-specific components can access application-level logic directly, though many people still recommend passing properties as it makes data flow clear and explicit.